# OPENSSL s_cient request fails (with 408 request timeout)

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl

I am trying to connect to  using openssl s_client api, command:

```
openssl s_client -connect <server1>:443
```

I am getting following output:

---------------------------------Start---------------------------

### CONNECTED(00000003)

### Certificate chain

### Server certificate

No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512

### Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits

SSL handshake has read 5540 bytes and written 302 bytes

### Verification error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
Protocol  : TLSv1.2
Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Session-ID: 
Session-ID-ctx: 
Master-Key: 
PSK identity: None
PSK identity hint: None
SRP username: None
Start Time: 1553089057
Timeout: 7200 (sec)
Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)

### Extended master secret: no

```
GET <path_to_api> HTTP/1.1
HOST: <server1>
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length:0
```

---

HTTP/1.1 408 REQUEST_TIMEOUT
Content-Length:0
Connection: Close

closed

--------------------------------End-------------------------------

It results in request time out.
If I use curl command it is successful.

What is the cause for the request timeout ?

Comment: There should be an empty line at the end of the HTTP header but you don't show one. This might be the cause of the problem. Apart from that content-length and content-type are irrelevant for GET requests since these have never content in the first place.

Comment: I gave an empty line like:

GET <api> HTTP/1.1
HOST: <server1>

But it is still giving me request time out.

Comment: It is hard to tell what is really going on since there is no way to reproduce for us what you are really doing. Note that the line end in HTTP has to be `\r\n` instead of just `\n`. Most servers accept both but it might be that your specific server is more picky and actually expects the client to adhere to standards. Try `-crlf` option with `s_client`.

Comment: what is this -crlf option for ?

Comment: -crlf option worked for me, but I did not understand how it worked. Also, what is its equivalent option for programming??

Comment: It might be helpful if you a) read the documentation of `-crlf` in the [man page for s_client](https://linux.die.net/man/1/s_client)  and b) make yourself familiar with the HTTP standard (the real standard and not just some examples you see) and c) understand the difference between `\r\n` and `\n`. Then you will probably understand.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich, It helped.
Solution: use crlf instead of just lf as few servers look for crlf as a line feed.

Comment: Yes, these few servers actually require you to be less ignorant of the HTTP standard than the others. No idea why they made the effort to create a protocol standard in the first place since it looks like the users don't care about what is standardized when trying to implement the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

-crlf option resolved the issue.
Thanks @SteffenUllrich

command:

```
openssl s_client -connect <server1>:443 -crlf
```